# csv file insert into mysql database which was the frequently appear record

Tags: mysql, csv, upload, insert, repeat

## question

i have a csv file like this:

```
char num  
aaa,123  
bbb,123  
bbb,123  
bbb,123  
ccc,123
```

i just want to insert into mysql database the most frequently appear record of
csv file -->which is [bbb,123]

so i hope the database is like this:
(key:num)

```
char num  
bbb,123
```

are there any way to achieve this?

## I have try like this

i have try like this:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE table
ADD PRIMARY KEY (char,num);
but the result is

```
char num  
aaa,123
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the specified resultset from a table loaded from the CSV:

```
SELECT c.char, c.num
  FROM loadtable c
 GROUP BY c.char, c.num
 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

To get the single row returned by the query into another table, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO another_table (char,num)
SELECT c.char, c.num
  FROM loadtable c
 GROUP BY c.char, c.num
 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the csv file already in the database at this point? I'm assuming so from your attempt, so you could try something like this:

```
SELECT char, num, MAX(count_column)
FROM
    (SELECT char, num, count(*) as count_column
    FROM table
    GROUP by 1, 2;)
```

Comment: yes,it works!maybe it's the only way to solve this problem.thanks!

Comment: This query is not guaranteed to return the specified resultset, because the values returned for `char` and `num` will not necessarily be the values associated with the maximum count.